# ORA-12541: TNS:no listener error even though listener is running

Tags: linux, oracle

I have installed Oracle 11g Express Edition on Linux (centOS). I am getting "ORA-12541: TNS:no listener" error even though service is running properly.

```
lsnrctl status
LSNRCTL for Linux: Version 11.2.0.2.0 - Production on 23-OCT-2018 16:22:49
Copyright (c) 1991, 2011, Oracle.  All rights reserved.
Connecting to (DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=IPC)(KEY=EXTPROC_FOR_XE)))
STATUS of the LISTENER
------------------------
Alias                     LISTENER
Version                   TNSLSNR for Linux: Version 11.2.0.2.0 - Production
Start Date                23-OCT-2018 16:07:26
Uptime                    0 days 0 hr. 15 min. 22 sec
Trace Level               off
Security                  ON: Local OS Authentication
SNMP                      OFF
Default Service           XE
Listener Parameter File   /u01/app/oracle/product/11.2.0/xe/network/admin/listener.ora
Listener Log File         /u01/app/oracle/diag/tnslsnr/ruchanjoshi/listener/alert/log.xml
Listening Endpoints Summary...
  (DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=ipc)(KEY=EXTPROC_FOR_XE)))
  (DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=tcp)(HOST=xxx.xx.xxx.xxx)(PORT=1521)))
Services Summary...
Service "PLSExtProc" has 1 instance(s).
  Instance "PLSExtProc", status UNKNOWN, has 1 handler(s) for this service...
Service "XE" has 1 instance(s).
  Instance "XE", status READY, has 1 handler(s) for this service...
Service "XEXDB" has 1 instance(s).
  Instance "XE", status READY, has 1 handler(s) for this service...
The command completed successfully
```

Can you please help me in connecting database on server itself as well as from remote desktop.

Comment: How are you trying to connect - where from (same box, same LAN, elsewhere), from which application/client, and with what connection string? The error suggests your connection attempt is using the wrong IP address or port number (or there's a firewall in the way, or maybe some NAT confusion, or hostname/IP confusion...)

Comment: @AlexPoole, I am trying to make connection from same box initially (I will go for remote connection in next phase). My TNSping is also working fine.

Comment: Look into logfile for more hints: /u01/app/oracle/diag/tnslsnr/ruchanjoshi/listener/alert/log.xml

Comment: @ruchajoshi - but how are you trying to connect? Please add the connection string you are trying to use to the question. I'd guess you're trying to use the hostname (and that doesn't resolve to the IP the listener is on) or localhost, rather than the actual IP/port the listener is using.

Comment: @AlexPoole I am trying to connect using service name XE. Please note tnsping works fine for XE.

sqlplus username/password@XE
SQL*Plus: Release 11.2.0.2.0 Production on Tue Oct 23 17:04:32 2018
Copyright (c) 1982, 2011, Oracle.  All rights reserved.
ERROR:
ORA-12541: TNS:no listener

Comment: Please [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/52947583/edit) to add information, particularly anything that needs to be formatted. Including your tnsnames.ora entry for XE might also be helpful. Also please show what you get from `sqlplus username/password@//xxx.xx.xxx.xx:1521/XE`. Though they should be equivalent really...